# Swift 5: TableView scroll to next cell

Tags: swift, xcode, tableview

Hi everyone I want some help on tableview with this `tableView.isPagingEnabled = true` when I call this he work but he not move to next cell with full height , how I can use it and move to next cell with full height,
[image]

this is my code :

```
import UIKit

private let id =  "ss"
class TableView:UITableViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: id)
        
        tableView.isPagingEnabled = true
        
    }
    
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        return 16
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: id, for: indexPath)
        
        cell.backgroundColor = .red
        return cell
        
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        
        return 755
    } 
}
```

I want my cell be like tiktok cell when I swipe down he move to next cell with full height ,

thank you

Comment: What is 755, it should depend on your screen size ?

Answer (score 0):

It really seems to me that what you want is to use a `UIPageView` instead of a `UITableView`.  Below is a playground that demonstrates using `UIPageView` to achieve the effect I think you are describing.  When the view displays, try scrolling up and down.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

func calibratedHue(hue: Int) -> Int {
    guard hue >= 0 else { return 0 }
    guard hue < 360 else { return 360 }

    return (hue / 12) * 12
}

class ColorPageViewController : UIViewController {
    var hue : Int = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(
            hue: CGFloat(self.hue) / 360.0,
            saturation: 1.0,
            brightness: 1.0,
            alpha: 1.0)

    }
}

class PagesOfColors : NSObject, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
                        viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        var priorViewController : UIViewController? = nil

        if let colorPageViewController = viewController as? ColorPageViewController {
            if colorPageViewController.hue > 0 {
                let newViewController = ColorPageViewController()

                newViewController.hue = calibratedHue(hue: colorPageViewController.hue - 12)
                priorViewController = newViewController
            }
        }

        return priorViewController
    }

    func pageViewController(
        _ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
        viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        var nextViewController : UIViewController? = nil

        if let colorPageViewController = viewController as? ColorPageViewController {
            if colorPageViewController.hue < 360 {
                let newViewController = ColorPageViewController()

                newViewController.hue = calibratedHue(hue: colorPageViewController.hue + 12)
                nextViewController = newViewController
            }
        }

        return nextViewController
    }
}


let pageViewController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .vertical)
let pageSource =  PagesOfColors()
let startingPage = ColorPageViewController()
startingPage.hue = calibratedHue(hue: 180)
pageViewController.setViewControllers([startingPage], direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
pageViewController.dataSource = pageSource
pageViewController.view.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 480)
PlaygroundSupport.PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = pageViewController
```